Law of Demeter in OOP - in simple Java class
I'm learning LoD, and I read below block from here

Simply put, the Law says that a method X of class C should only invoke the methods of:

Class C itself
An object created by X
An object passed as an argument to X
An object held in an instance variable of C
A static field


I try to put together a class myself as follows.
public class C {

    X4 x4 = new X4();

    public static final X5 X_5 = new X5();


    public String cMethod() {
        return "C so cool bean!";
    }

    public String x1() {
        return cMethod() + "\t hell yeah!";
    }

    public void x2() {
        X2 x2 = new X2();
        x2.sayHello();
    }

    public void x3(X3 x3) {
        x3.x3Method();
    }

    public void x4() {
        x4.x4Method();
    }

    public static void x5() {
        X_5.x5Method();
    }

}

I tried asking 3 AI models (ChatGPT 3.5, Gemini, Claude 3 Sonnet)
Every one of them provides different opinion,
for method cMethod, x1 and x3, these follows LoD no doubt,
but what about x2, x4, x5 ?
Questions listed below:

Regarding violating LoD or not, does it matter that internal object -- X4 here, is accessed directly or by getter?
If creating an instance inside x2 method is fine, how can x2 method be improved to follow LoD?
I'm guessing x4 violates LoD because of the same reason as x2, access the instance's method inside clacc C? If so, how to improve this? Because AIs just declare another class with a method, and remain the exact method code as x4. And said that since it has an interface, it's ok now.
x5 is simplifed, if to focus on whether calling a static field's method inside method x of class C, does it violates LoD?

I know for some it's time wasting to focus on theory or principles rather than real life challenge.
If any one can give some pointers that'll be fantastic.

don't ask AI generators. Seriously. What do you mean, x4 is used directly, not through getter? Is there anything in that code that doesn't work? If it doesn't, just assume it's not a violation. I don't see a problem with x2 or x4, and if x5method is a static method, I don't see a problem with that neither. Where would you call a method if not IN a method? Besides instantiation/declaration everything is done in blocks or methods

I don't understand why x2, x4 and x5 should violate the LoD: the x2 method calls an instance method on an object it creates which is allowed according to the second bullet point. x4 calls an instance method on an object held in an instance field (allowed by the fourth bullet point) and x5 calls an instance method on an object held in a static field (allowed by the fifth bullet point).

Honestly, the example of the violation shown there is ... a bit odd to me. Do they have Managers that aren't employees? Why would they allow an(y) employee to do 'manager only' tasks? Why would they allow employees to basically directly approve expenses? Whether or not chained calls are allowed, is more of an opinion

@Stultuske Thanks for the comment. I'm the only Java programmar in the office, so I kinda just went to AI. And about x4 is used directly, I mean in x4 (method) I explicitly call x4 instead of getX4(). The code works but LoD isn't about whether the code works or not, I assume?
Second comment: yeah... that's one of the reason I asked AI cause that article could be wrong, maybe? Can't just trust anything on the internet even though that site has tons of good Java related info.

@ThomasKläger Hello, thanks for your reply. Yes! I honestly don't understand why AIs think these methods violate LoD, and that's the reason I posted this question :/

@FusRoDaheim why would a getter be needed? It's instantiated within the class itself, so it follows those laws

Does this help? Law of Demeter original definition

@jaco0646 Thank you! This definitely clear the doubts in my head.

All your methods do not violate the Law of Demeter.
On Wikipedia there is a good explanation for object-oriented programming.

In particular, an object should avoid invoking methods of an object
returned by another method. For many modern object-oriented languages
that use a dot as field identifier, the law can be stated simply as
"use only one dot". That is, the code a.m().n() breaks the law where
a.m() does not.

